# how to extract features using histogram

Tags: arrays

I wrote this code to extract features using histogram but i get this error saying. Please you help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance
ValueError : shape too big to be a matrix

#load image dataset of length 400000

```
train_x=r'/home/data/Desktop/SAT-4/train_x.mat' 
train_x=loadmat(train_x)

len (train_x) = 400000
```

#extract features using histogram function

```
def train_hist():

   my_hist[]

   for i in range(len(train_x)):
       new_train_x =histogram (array(mat(train_x)))
       my_hist1 = my_hist.append(new_train_x)
   return my_hist1

my_hist1 = train_hist()
```

ValueError : shape too big to be a matrix